# OutOfMemory problems in viewpager with imageviews

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, out-of-memory, universal-image-loader

I have a memory leak (I guess?), somewhere in my app. And i really have no idea where, i have been trying to follow several link explaining different ways to close OOM errors, but without luck.

The thing is, i have a viewpager with 209 pages (data loaded dynamically, and the same single fragment is being used for all 209 pages)

I can scroll through around 20 pages or so before i start getting any memory errors.
All images are loaded by Universal-Image-Loader and are only cached on disc, not in memory.

I am using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Heres the code, i really hope you guys can find something i cant.. Also, if you find anything that should be different, can be optimized or anything, please do tell. :

Activity:

```
public class MovieInfo extends SherlockFragmentActivity{

    MyAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;
    static ArrayList<Movie> items;

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object o) {
            View view = (View)o;
            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView(view);
            view = null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment f = new MovieInfoFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putParcelable("item", items.get(position));
            f.setArguments(args); 
            return f;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.movie_info_pager);


        int mIndex = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("index", 0);
        DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        items = (ArrayList<Movie>) db.getAllMovies();
        db.close();



        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mIndex);
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class MovieInfoFragment extends SherlockFragment{


    private boolean clearArt = true;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    private Movie movie;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle data = getArguments();
        movie = data.getParcelable("item");

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheOnDisc()
        .resetViewBeforeLoading()
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
        .build();

    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_info, container, false);

        if(movie != null){

            final ImageView clearArtID = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Movie_InfoClearArt);
            final TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Movie_InfoTitle);
            final TextView genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Movie_InfoGenre);

            if(clearArt && movie.getClearArt() != null){
                clearArtID.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                title.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
                genre.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
            }else{
                clearArtID.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
                title.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                genre.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
            }

            ImageView fanart = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Movie_InfoFanart);
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(movie.getFanart(), fanart, options);
            final TextView lineone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Movie_InfoLineOneText);
            final TextView linetwo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Movie_InfoLineTwoText);
            final ImageView cover = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Movie_InfoCover);
            final Movie mov = movie;
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(movie.getThumb(), cover, options);
            if(clearArt && movie.getClearArt() != null){
                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(movie.getClearArt(), clearArtID, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) { }    

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                            FailReason failReason) {
                        clearArtID.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
                        title.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                        genre.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                        title.setText(mov.getTitle().toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
                        genre.setText(mov.getGenreString());
                        lineone.setText(String.valueOf(mov.getDirectorString()));
                        linetwo.setText("WRITER");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) { }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) { }
                });
                lineone.setText(movie.getGenreString());
                linetwo.setText(movie.getDirectorString());
            }else{
                title.setText(movie.getTitle().toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
                genre.setText(movie.getGenreString());
                lineone.setText(String.valueOf(movie.getDirectorString()));
                linetwo.setText("WRITER");
            }
            TextView rating = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Movie_InfoRating);
            rating.setText(movie.getRating() + " / 10");
            TextView runtime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Movie_InfoRuntime);
            runtime.setText(movie.getPlaytime()/60 + " min");
            TextView year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Movie_InfoYear);
            year.setText(String.valueOf(movie.getYear()));

            HorizontalListView listview = (HorizontalListView) view.findViewById(R.id.Movie_InfoActorList);  
            listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);  

            TextView plot = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Movie_InfoPlot);
            plot.setText(movie.getPlot());

            if(movie.getCdart() != null){
                ImageView cdArt = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Movie_InfoCD);
                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(movie.getCdart(), cdArt, options);
            }
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I do know, that the reason my app is getting OutOfMemory errors is, that it doesn't release the bitmaps in my large viewpager for garbage collection, but how do i get my app to release them? (read: garbage collect) when the are not currently in view, single previous or single next "slide"?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Try to find leaks following this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html). (On api >=3.0, early bitmaps was stored in the native heap)

Comment: Thank you ;) I will try following the method described in the article and return with my findings ..

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be calling the super implementation of the destroyItem method

Comment: Tried adding it to the end of my destroyItem, sadly it didn't change anything :/